# Using Factory Girl with Rspec Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

So I want to test some views using Rspec and Factory Girl, but I don't know how to assign a factory to a view properly.  All of the information I see online uses stubbing, and although stubbing is fine, I want to keep my rspec stuff somewhat consistent.

I want to use a factory for an edition model and associate that with the page when I render the page, but everything I've considered seems to be broken.  Here's sort of a ridiculous example:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "catalog/editions/rationale.html.haml" do
  before do
    @edition = Factory.create(:edition)
    assign(:editions, @edition)
    render :action => 'rationale', :id => @edition
  end
  context "GET rationale" do
    it "should not have the preamble to the United States constitution" do
      rendered.should_not contain(/We the People of the United States/)
    end
  end
end
```

In this I've tried changing render :action => 'rationale', :id => @edition to just render, and other similar tweaks to the render action. I just have no idea where to start a factory_girl helped view.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Versions:

Rails 3.0.10

RSpec 2.7

Factory_Girl 2.2

Comment: Can you give some more details on what the issue is exactly?  Where is the test failing?

Comment: Also, what version of Rails, FactoryGirl and RSpec are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the error is that `@editions` is expecting an array, so you should write

```
assign(:editions, [@edition])
```

or, otherwise, if it should be a single element, you should write:

```
assign(:edition, @edition)
```

Secondly, unless your view is a partial that expects variables, you should just write

```
render
```

You do not have to give the action, rspec knows which view to render from the `describe`, and the view does not retrieve any data (so you don't have to set the id), you just have to set the instance variables correctly using the `assigns`. Testing the view does nothing more than rendering the view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You were absolutely right, and this is sort of what I had in the beginning, but it didn't work. What I found out I was doing wrong is I wasn't initializing all of the variables required in the controller/view.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've got the answer, stop writing view specs. They are needlessly hard to write, and they really don't test enough to be at all worthwhile. Do your view and controller testing with Cucumber instead.