# view test using rspec & factory girl error: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, rspec2

I am fairly new to Ruby & Rails; have not done much programming; but have a tech background.

I've built a very small amount of functionality mostly based on Railscasts and want to go with TDD, and am going back and trying to build some simple tests before moving forward.

I'm stuck on a test of a view and can not find anything similar enough to figure out how to resolve this.  I've looked thru the Railscasts, The RSpec book, etc., and have done a lot of searches.

The desired functionality seems to work fine, but the test fails.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

**Error:**

```
 Failure/Error: render
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"email_verifies", :id=>nil}
 # ./app/views/email_verifies/edit.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_email_verifies_edit_html_haml__3756516833416545914_70345184965780'
 # ./spec/views/email_verifies/edit.html.haml_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Code:**

app/views/email_verifies/edit.html.haml

```
%h1 Verify Email Address

= form_for @user, :url => email_verify_path(params[:id]) do |f|

  .actions
    = f.submit "Verify Email Address"
```

spec/views/email_verifies/edit.html.haml_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "email_verifies/edit.html.haml" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email_verify_token => "anything") }
  it "displays the text on the rendered page" do
    render
    rendered.should have_content("Verify Email Address")
  end
end
```

spec/factories/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence :email do |n|
      "foo#{n}@example.com" 
    end
    password "secret"
  end
end
```

part of app/controllers/email_verifies_controller.rb
(there is no 'show' action in this controller)

```
def edit
  @user = User.find_by_email_verify_token(params[:id])
  unless @user
    redirect_to signup_path, :alert => "This email verification has expired.  Please sign up again."
  end
end
```

**Some of the routes:**

```
edit_email_verify GET    /email_verifies/:id/edit(.:format)  email_verifies#edit  
     email_verify GET    /email_verifies/:id(.:format)       email_verifies#show  
email_verifies    GET    /email_verifies(.:format)           email_verifies#index  
edit_email_verify GET    /email_verifies/:id/edit(.:format)  email_verifies#edit  
     email_verify GET    /email_verifies/:id(.:format)       email_verifies#show  
                  PUT    /email_verifies/:id(.:format)       email_verifies#update
```

**Versions:**

ruby 1.9.3p362
rails (3.2.13)
factory_girl (4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unfamiliar with this syntax, but based on the error, i think the problem is here:

```
  it "displays the text on the rendered page" do
    render #HERE!
    rendered.should have_content("Verify Email Address")
  end
```

in any case the problem is that the edit action (which is, i think, what you're trying to test here) needs an `:id` so it knows what email to edit - check out the output of `rake routes`

```
edit_email_verify GET    /email_verifies/:id/edit(.:format)
```

you need to include an `:id` in that render call - this might work:

change

```
it "displays the text on the rendered page" do
  render
  rendered.should have_content("Verify Email Address")
end
```

to

```
it "displays the text on the rendered page" do
  render edit_email_verify_path(@user) #the @user might need to be changed 
                                       #depending on what the `:id` refers to
  rendered.should have_content("Verify Email Address")
end
```

## update

> I just tried `render edit_email_verify_path(:id => user.email_verify_token)`, and it seems to pass the correct `:id`, and then gets the error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing partial /email_verifies/anything/edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}
```

Should have seen this before, but the problem is here:

```
Missing partial /email_verifies/****anything****/edit
```

The `:id` in `/email_verifies/:id/edit` is the users `:id` so  you should try

```
render edit_email_verify_path(user)
```

which will return `/email_verifies/[your users id]/edit`

Comment: Thanks.  I think you're right, but I've tried looking up details on render syntax and haven't come up with something that works.  I couldn't find any similar examples either.  Seems like it should be simple, but I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: A little progress...the error changed to:
`No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"email_verifies", :id=>nil}`
As far as I can tell, the :id should be the email_verify_token, but It's not getting passed using the render.  When I tested some similar code that created a variable instead of using 'let', it did write the email_verify_token correctly to the test db.

Comment: I just tried `render edit_email_verify_path(:id => user.email_verify_token)`, and it seems to pass the correct :id, and then gets the error `ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing partial /email_verifies/anything/edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}`

Comment: I think it's in the right place, it's the first one listed above under 'Code:', and I also put the path above the code in case that was an issue, which is: `app/views/email_verifies/edit.html.haml`

Comment: Your update is probably a good assumption, but in this case, it's actually using the 'email_verify_token' as the ':id' passed to the edit action in the controller to do a lookup by that token as seen in this line (shown above in the code section): `@user = User.find_by_email_verify_token(params[:id])`; at least that's my understanding of this.  And in the browser running on the local dev server, it is that token in the url.

Comment: it's showing that in the browser, but it's only working because rails is smart enough to pull what it needs - your error was `Missing partial /email_verifies/anything/edit` - think about what that's saying - it can't find an object to edit, and the way it would find it would be via an `:id` - in this case the user id.  give it a try and see if it works (at least in the testing suite)

Comment: Sorry for the response delay @dax.  I tried `render edit_email_verify_path(:id => user.id)` and got pretty much the same error: `Missing partial /email_verifies/3/edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, ...`.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943744/missing-partial-error-in-rails-3

Comment: I tried copying `app/views/email_verifies/edit.html.haml` to (same path) `_edit.html.haml`, and even `_edit.html`, & `_edit.haml` just in case, and get the same error as above, `Missing partial /email_verifies/anything/edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, ...`.  I found a question (in next comment, ran out of space), in which 'nathanvda' says 'Secondly, unless your view is a partial that expects variables, you should just write' `render` (leaves out any following code completely), so I'm wondering if in our code, the `render edit_email_verify_path...` why it's looking for a partial.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187944/using-factory-girl-with-rspec-views

While I really appreciate your persistance @dax, and hate to give up, I'm starting to think we might want to stop pursuing this question, and maybe after I have more experience, I'll be able to rewrite the test, or as the last poster in the above referenced question says, just stop writing view specs altogether and use Cucumber, since 'They are needlessly hard to write, and they really don't test enough to be at all worthwhile'.